# Using Select Scope_Identity() with a store procedure

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

I am writing some code that would insert user data into database using a stored procedure (sp_AddNewUser). The stored procedure just inserts into the data into the database. I was wondering if I could use SCOPE_IDENTITY() function with a stored procedure without editing the stored procedure.

```
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_AddNewUser", conn);
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@firstname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =   row.Cells[_dicDef["firstname"]].Value;
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@lastname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = row.Cells[_dicDef["lastname"]].Value;
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  //NOT SURE WHAT TO DO AFTER THIS COMMENT ----
  string sql = "SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)";
  cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
  newID = (Int 32_cmd.ExecuteScalar(); //<---- will this return the latest id?

}
```

Comment: why don't you try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot use it this way. As [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) states:

> Returns the last identity value inserted into an identity column **in the same scope**. A scope is a module: a stored procedure, trigger, function, or batch. Therefore, two statements are in the same scope if they are in the same stored procedure, function, or batch.

It won't work for you as your two statements are not in the same scope and `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` doesn't return anything.

Using `@@IDENTITY` in this case will return the value you need:

> @@IDENTITY will return the last identity column value inserted across any scope in the current session

You have to be careful though to make sure it is the proper identity (should be ok in the example above).

Comment: I am not sure how to implement that. this is what I have so far            'code'                     
//Ran stored procedure to insert user
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    //Get ID of last Insert
                    string sql = "SELECT newID = @@IDENITY";
                    cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                    int newID = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar(); 'code'
could you guide me?

Comment: Your query could be just `SELECT @@IDENITY` but it looks good.

Comment: When I run this code:
`string sql = "SELECT @@IDENITY"; cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
int newID = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();`
I get an error: 
`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Must declare the scalar variable "@@IDENITY"`

Comment: Sorry, stupid typo. Should be @@IDENTITY, I missed one T

Comment: well the error is gone.. thanks, but im getting an error with the casting part: 'newID = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar(); 
thanks!

Comment: Actually, `SELECT @@IDENTITY` returns a decimal for some odd reason. Change the query to `SELECT cast(@@IDENTITY as int)`, your cast will be valid then. Sorry, I didn't know that.